# Jquery UI Datepicker breaking in IE11

Tags: css, jquery-ui

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ch8a3qmL/1/)

I'm using Jquery UI to display a calalnder which works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE11 it's rendering the date rows huge.

Here is how it looks in IE 11

[image: IE Problems]

Here is how it looks on Firefox and Chrome

[image: Normal]

This is the css I've wrote to modify the cells to look the way I want

```
 .ui-datepicker {
        width: 17em;
        padding: .2em .2em 0;
        display: none;
        width: 333px !important;
        background-image: none;
    }

    .ui-widget-header {
        background: none !important;
        border: none !important;
    }

    .ui-widget-content { background: none !important; }

    .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header {
        position: relative;
        padding: .2em 0;
    }

    .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next {
        position: absolute;
        top: 2px;
        width: 1.8em;
        height: 1.8em;
    }

    .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev-hover, .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next-hover { top: 1px; }

    .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev { left: 2px; }

    .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next { right: 2px; }

    .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev-hover { left: 1px; }

    .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next-hover { right: 1px; }

    .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev span, .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next span {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -8px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -8px;
    }

    .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title {
        margin: 0 2.3em;
        line-height: 1.8em;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title select {
        font-size: 1em;
        margin: 1px 0;
    }

    .ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month-year { width: 100%; }

    .ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month,
    .ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-year {
        width: 39%;
        border: none;
    }

    .ui-datepicker table {
        /*width: 100%;
           font-size: .9em;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: 0 0 .4em;*/
        width: 341px;
        height: 216px;
        font-size: small;
        font-family: Open Sans;
        color: rgb(214, 214, 214); 

        background-color: rgb(62, 62, 62);
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    .ui-datepicker th {
        padding: .7em .3em;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 100;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        height: 25px;
        border: 0;
    }

    .ui-datepicker a:hover {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: 800;
    }

    .ui-datepicker td {
        border: 0;
        padding: 1px;
    }

    .ui-datepicker td span, .ui-datepicker td a {
        display: block;
        padding: .2em;
        text-align: right;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane {
        background-image: none;
        margin: .7em 0 0 0;
        padding: 0 .2em;
        border-left: 0;
        border-right: 0;
        border-bottom: 0;
    }

    .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button {
        float: right;
        margin: .5em .2em .4em;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: .2em .6em .3em .6em;
        width: auto;
        overflow: visible;
    }

    .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button.ui-datepicker-current { float: left; }

    /* with multiple calendars */

    .ui-datepicker.ui-datepicker-multi { width: auto; }

    .ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group { float: left; }

    .ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group table {
        width: 95%;
        margin: 0 auto .4em;
    }

    .ui-datepicker-multi-2 .ui-datepicker-group { width: 50%; }

    .ui-datepicker-multi-3 .ui-datepicker-group { width: 33.3%; }

    .ui-datepicker-multi-4 .ui-datepicker-group { width: 25%; }

    .ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group-last .ui-datepicker-header { border-left-width: 0; }

    .ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group-middle .ui-datepicker-header { border-left-width: 0; }

    .ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-buttonpane { clear: left; }

    .ui-datepicker-row-break {
        clear: both;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 0em;
    }

    /* RTL support */

    .ui-datepicker-rtl { direction: rtl; }

    .ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-prev {
        right: 2px;
        left: auto;
    }

    .ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-next {
        left: 2px;
        right: auto;
    }

    .ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-prev:hover {
        right: 1px;
        left: auto;
    }

    .ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-next:hover {
        left: 1px;
        right: auto;
    }

    .ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-buttonpane { clear: right; }

    .ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button { float: left; }

    .ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button.ui-datepicker-current { float: right; }

    .ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-group { float: right; }

    .ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-group-last .ui-datepicker-header {
        border-right-width: 0;
        border-left-width: 1px;
    }

    .ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-group-middle .ui-datepicker-header {
        border-right-width: 0;
        border-left-width: 1px;
    }

    /* IE6 IFRAME FIX (taken from datepicker 1.5.3 */

    .ui-datepicker-cover {
        display: none; /*sorry for IE5*/
        display/**/: block; /*sorry for IE5*/
        position: absolute; /*must have*/
        z-index: -1; /*must have*/
        filter: mask(); /*must have*/
        top: -4px; /*must have*/
        left: -4px; /*must have*/
        width: 200px; /*must have*/
        height: 200px; /*must have*/
    }
```

If you use the JSFiddle on the top you can see the difference. I've been inspecting elements and trying to change things to get it to render right in IE but haven't got it to work yet. I was hoping someone could shed some light on this problem.

Comment: Have you tried using a **reset.css** file to 'normalize' the browsers?

Comment: I just did, no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I look at the DOM I see `<tbody style="height:182px;">`. When I comment out the height it works as expected. It looks like ie honors height styles on tbody while other browsers do not.

Comment: I used qjuery to fix it from this point, if firefox then remove height style. Works on all 3 now.

Comment: Pff, been debugging something similar for the past hour. Thanks m8!